# Can we declare empty arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How to declare empty array so that I can enter any number of elements I want. I have tried following codes but they are not working.

```
   String newValues[] = new String[];

   String newValues[] = new String[] {};
```

Comment: "empty array so that i can enter any number of elements i want": an array always has a fixed length. If you are looking for a dynamic structure use a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using-

```
ArrayList<String> newarray = new ArrayList<String>();
newarray.add("string1");
newarray.add("string2");
//so on.....
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have fixed sizes. What you want is called a `List`.

```
List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>();
newValues.add("hello");
```

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by:

```
ArrayList<String> your_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can add afterwards any number of elements as you want using the `.add(...)` method. The way you proposed it's not possible since you have to know it's size at declaration time.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do so, array must be declared by its size or contents:

```
String newValues[] = new String[10] {}; //now you can set those 10 objects
String newValues[] = new String[] {"string1","string2"}; // already set 2 strings
```

If you wan to declare an empty array and then add something into it you should use Collections instead. Like ArrayList for instance:

```
List <String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>();
newValues.add("string1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList` instead.

```
List<String> list = ArrayList<String>();
```